# Show menu item to all users, prompt for credentials for anonymous

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I have an item in the navbar that links to a page view which can only be accessed by authenticated users.

I want the menu item visible for anonymous users, and also to have them redirected to login if they try to access it. This seems like a common use-case. I see a plethora of modules that accomplish this in Drupal 7, but I don't see any for Drupal 8.

How can I show the navbar for anonymous users that prompts users to login with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, Drupal excludes menu links that the user doesn't have permission to view.

One way around this is to build a menu specifically for anonymous users using the same titles as your other menu, but all pointing to the **/user/login?destination=my/view/path** path. Once the that menu is built, you can create a menu block from it that only displays for the *anonymous user* role.

After adjusting the original menu block such that it only displays for the *authenticated user* role, you will effectively have menu items that display for both roles and prompts a user to login when viewing anonymously. For good measure, you might want to set your Basic site settings such that 403 requests are redirected to **/user/login** in case the user navigates to the views page directly.

Comment: How do I tell the new menu to only appear for anon users?  Also, I temporarily changed the href of my menu item from /my/view/path to /user/login?destination=my/view/path.  Users still get in, anon members still see it, are there any disadvantages to just leaving it this way? Other than the URL not being as pretty as it could have been...

Comment: On the block administration page there's a *Roles* section that lets you set the block's visibility for specified roles

Comment: I got it working by following your instructions.  Thanks a bunch